# String of XML text in spring XML model always being escaped - how to prevent

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, escaping, html-escape-characters

I have requirement to upload schema free XML documents which I can then retrieve later. I wont ever know the schema/format of the XML and any of the elements it contains so I de-serialising the whole document as a string in the spring boot controller.

I then add the whole string as an element named 'content' to a model. 
When I return the model back from the controller it is always being escaped for me (thanks Spring, that's usually exactly what we all want). 
for example

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<articles>
  <content>
        &lt;note&gt; &lt;to&gt;Tove&lt;/to&gt; &lt;from&gt;Jani&lt;/from&gt; &lt;heading&gt;Reminder&lt;/heading&gt; &lt;body&gt;Don't forget me this weekend!&lt;/body&gt; &lt;/note&gt;
  </content>
</articles>
```

when it should be something like

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<articles>
  <content>       
    <note>
      <to>Tove</to>
      <from>Jani</from>
      <heading>Reminder</heading>
      <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
    </note>
  </content>
</articles>
```

But in my case I really need the string in the content element of the model to look like just an XML element.

Is there a way to achieve this. I have searched for ages. I can manually try to unescape and if I print to the console it has worked but a soon as I return this from the controller it is escaped again.

Is there a way to disable escaping for a particular model?

I'd be really grateful for any direction; I have not found anything helpful anywhere.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not with a model. Send an entity, the bytes of which are the XML you want sent.

Comment: That is what I have done. I think I would need to know what data is in the xml so I can map it explicitly.